# Flask - How to handle errors that doesn't has a decorator for it?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I have some decorators to handle specific errors from my application like `AuthError` or `AppError`.

Now I want to handle *all* other errors that are different from `AuthError` or `AppError`. Is possible to create a "generic" decorator that get other Exceptions?

For now, my code is:

```
@api.errorhandler(AuthError)
def handle_auth_error(ex):    
    logging.warn('An auth error has happened.', ex)
    return { 'message': ex.error}, ex.status_code

@api.errorhandler(AppError)
def handle_app_error(ex):    
    logging.error('An app error has happened.', ex)
    return { 'message': ex.error}, ex.status_code
```

Comment: `@api.errorhandler(Exception)`?

Comment: `@api.errorhandler(Exception)` will not start to handle `AppError` and `AuthError`?

Comment: If you want to handle all other errors using a custom handler, you can override the default handler using just `@api.errorhandler` instead.

Comment: @joaovictortr just remove class from ()? woot, python is magic

Comment: Indeed, as the documentation states for the error handlers (https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors.html#the-api-errorhandler-decorator). When flask-restplus can't find a proper handler, it uses the default one, which can be overriden by using `@api.errorhandler`, without any exceptions.